# bootstrap.js Modal button fires one click per every previously opened modal

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying to open a modal window with bootstrap modal to edit a backbone model. Everything seems to go right until I try the same thing a second time. After clicking the modal button, I receive an event per every previously opened modal (doesn't matter if previous modals were closed with the close/cancel button).

This behaviour is the same as shown in this issue: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/6828 but I wasn't able to extrapolate the solution to my code.

This is my first approach to bootstrap and backbone and I suppose I have misunderstood something. I'm showing a table with countries. Every row is ended with 2 buttons (edit and delete). When you click one of this buttons, the (single) country view, captures the event, includes the modal in the dom tree and shows it (event "click .editar"):

```
    var PaisModelView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: 'tr',
    template: null,
    editarPaisView: null,
    editarPaisTemplate: null,

    // Eventos
    events: {
        'click .editar' : 'editar'
    },

    // Inicializar
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.model = options.model;
        this.template = options.template;
        this.editarPaisTemplate = options.editarPaisTemplate;
        this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
        this.model.bind("destroy", this.close, this);
    },

    // Renderizar
    render: function(item) {
        if ($('#editarPais') != null) {
            $('#editarPais').modal('hide');
        }
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },

editar: function(item) {
    item.preventDefault();
            // creates the view
    this.editarPaisView = new EditarPaisView({
        editarPaisTemplate : this.editarPaisTemplate, 
        pais : this.model
    });
            // creates the modal window
    $("#body").append(this.editarPaisView.render().el);
            // opens the modal window
    $('#editarPais').modal('show');
},

    close:function () {
        alert('Not implemented');
    }
});
```

I use a separate view for the country model edition form:

```
var EditarPaisView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // Elemento html
    el: $('#mensajes'),
    template: null,
    pais: null,

    // Eventos
    events: {
        'click .confirmarEditar' : 'modificar',
    },


    initialize: function(options) {
        this.template = options.editarPaisTemplate;
        this.pais = options.pais;
    },
    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html(this.template({pais:this.pais}));       
        return this;
    },

    modificar: function(item){
        item.preventDefault();

        var nombrePaisEditado = document.getElementById("nombrePais").value;
        var codigoPaisEditado = document.getElementById("codigoPais").value;
        var valorPaisEditado = document.getElementById("valorPais").value;      

        this.pais.save({
                nombrePais: nombrePaisEditado,
                codigoPais: codigoPaisEditado,
                valorPais: valorPaisEditado
            },{
                success: function(){
                    console.log('Actualizado el país');
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('Se ha producido un error durante la actualización del país');
                },
                wait: true,
                async: true
            });
    }
});
```

So when you click the button with class "confirmarEditar" in the modal, the country model is saved.

The html code for each view is in a separate template file. This one is for country model:

```
<td><%= nombrePais %></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><%= codigoPais %></td>
<td style="text-align: right;"><%= valorPais %></td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
    <a href="#editarPais" role="button" class="btn btn-mini editar" id="editar_<%=idPais%>"><i class="icon-edit"></i>Editar</a>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
    <a href="#eliminarPais" role="button" class="btn btn-mini eliminar" id="eliminar_<%=idPais%>"
            data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-trash"></i>Eliminar</a>
</td>
```

And this one is for the country model edition form:

```
<div id="editarPais" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editarPaisLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="eliminarPaisLabel">Editar País</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <input type="hidden" id="idPais" value="<%= pais.get('idPais') %>">
    <p>                                 
        Nombre: <input type="text" id="nombrePais" maxlength="64" value="<%= pais.get('nombrePais') %>"/> <br>
        Código: <input type="text" id="codigoPais" maxlength="2" value="<%= pais.get('codigoPais') %>"/> <br>
        Valor:  <input type="text" id="valorPais" value="<%= pais.get('valorPais') %>"/> <br>       
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancelar</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary confirmarEditar">Editar</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Finally, these are the related libraries I'm using:

```
<script src="${contextPath}/static/lib/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="${contextPath}/static/lib/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="${contextPath}/static/lib/backbone-0.9.2.js"></script>
<script src="${contextPath}/static/lib/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Any help will be really appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be as simple as not recreating the modal div. Try this:

```
editar: function(item) {
    item.preventDefault();
    // creates the view
    this.editarPaisView = new EditarPaisView({
        editarPaisTemplate : this.editarPaisTemplate, 
        pais : this.model
    });

    // creates or updates the modal window
    if ($('#editarPais').length > 0) {
        $("#editarPais").replaceWith(this.editarPaisView.render().el);
    } else {
        $("#body").append(this.editarPaisView.render().el);
    }

    // opens the modal window
    $('#editarPais').modal('show');
},
```

Comment: As you point, `$('#editarPais').length` returns 1 after the first execution, but `replaceWith()` didn't solve the problem ( I didn't debug the result, just patched the code and saw what happens)